# React Material-UI not justify-content will not work for all of my Cards

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I'm having really bizarre issue with my code.  I am using React to map a Redux state onto Material-UI cards. When I was testing different styling on my cards the other day I was able to make different classes and update the card appearance however I liked.  However today when I added new information to my database the new cards will not take all of the styling from the Material-UI database.  Specifically it seems like the new cards are not effected by justifyContent.

This is a difficult issue for me to explain but basically I have a database of information being mapped onto multiple different cards.  Some of the cards are accepting the Material-UI styling other cards are not.

I would like to post a jsfiddle but I would need to link it to my database and I'm not sure that can be done.

Here is the page which is mapping my redux state:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ProjectItem from '../ProjectItem/ProjectItem'
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from '../Header/Header'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const mapReduxStateToProps = (reduxState) => ({reduxState});

const styles = theme => ({
    bodyContent: {
        marginTop: 100,
    }
})

class ProjectPage extends Component {

    //This calls the getProjects function on the page load
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getProjects();
    }

    //This function dispatches an action to our index page
    getProjects = () => {
        console.log('running')
        this.props.dispatch({ type: 'GET_PROJECT'})
    }

  render() {
    const {classes} = this.props
    return (
      <div>
          <Header />
          <div className= {classes.bodyContent}>
        {this.props.reduxState.projects.map((project,index) => {
            return(

                <ProjectItem 
                    key = {index}
                    id = {project.id}
                    name ={project.name}
                    description = {project.description}
                    thumbnail = {project.thumbnail}
                    website = {project.website}
                    github = {project.github}
                    tag_id = {project.tag_id}
                />

            )
        })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapReduxStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(ProjectPage)));
```

And here is the page with my styling.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './ProjectItem.css'
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia'
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const mapReduxStateToProps = (reduxState) => ({reduxState});

const styles = theme => ({
    card: {
        display: 'flex',
        width: 550,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        height: 150,
        paddingTop: 5,
        paddingBottom:5,

    },
    details: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column'
    },
    thumbnail: {
        height: 150,
        minWidth: 150
    },
    contentBody: {
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        textAlign: 'left',
        alignItems: 'center',
        display : 'inline-flex',
    },
    toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar
})
class ProjectItem extends Component {



  render() {
      const {classes} = this.props
    return (
        <div className='container'>
          <Card className={classes.card}>
              <CardMedia
                  className={classes.thumbnail}
                  image={this.props.thumbnail}
                  title="Project Image"
              />
              <div className={classes.details}>
                  <CardContent className={classes.contentBody}>
                      <Typography variant='h5'>
                        {this.props.name} 
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography variant='h6'>
                        <a href={this.props.github}>GitHub</a>  
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography variant='h6'>
                        <a href={this.props.website}>Website</a>
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography variant='h6'>
                        {this.props.tag_id}
                      </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                  <CardContent className={classes.content}>    
                      <Typography>
                          {this.props.description}
                      </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
              </div>
          </Card>
          </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapReduxStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(ProjectItem));
```

Comment: Please create sandbox snippet, very efficiently you could receive help :)
https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Did you add `display : 'inline-flex'` between you tests?